# Windows Phone 8 App Share Content

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, sharing

I have searched on the net regarding how to implement share content and found that we can use `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer` namespace to share the content on Windows Phone 8 App too. But I am getting error that this namespace is not supported on Windows Phone 8.

Can you guys please tell me if there is some other way to share the contents like PDF file in a Windows Phone 8 app. I have created a program which captures an image & then converts the image to PDF file now I want this converted PDF file to be shared, but unable to do using `Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer` namespace.

Any input will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The "Windows 8 way" does not work on Windows Phone 8. You need to use uri or file associations, more info at [Auto-launching apps using file and URI associations for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)